# cannot find symbol error using javax.soud.midi

Tags: java, compilation, javasound

i am currently trying to follow along the "Head First Java" book.

Half way in the book they program a "Music Machine" to explain some principles along the way.

Sadly i cant figure out how to get rid of this compiling-error:

```
    MusicTest1.java:6 error: connot find symbol
      Sequencer sequencer = new MidiSystem.getSequencer();
                                          ^
      symbol:    class getSequencer
      location:  class MidiSystem
1 error
```

that is the code:

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class MusicTest1{
    public void play(){
        try{
            Sequencer sequencer = new MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            System.out.println("yay made a sequencer object");
        }catch(MidiUnavailableException ex){
            System.out.println("failed to make sequencer object");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MusicTest1 mt = new MusicTest1();
        mt.play();
    }
}
```

Can this be a problem because in the book they use java 5.0 and i use java 8 on a virtual machine, or did i just make a typing error i didn't find?
Thank you!

Comment: `MidiSystem.getSequencer()` is a static method to get `Sequencer` object, so just remove `new`(as you dont create new `MidiSystem()` object) keyword and it should work

Comment: "Yay made a sequencer object!" thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as m.cekiera commented i added a wrong `new` when trying to get a sequencer object from the `MidiSystem.getSequencer()` method.